# Поднять локальный сервер

Tags: c#, сервер, localhost

Доброе время суток. 
Хочу сделать локальный сервер на C#
Те чтобы программа получала запросы которые идут на localhost, и отдавала ответы на запросы.
В какую сторону начинать смотреть, чтобы реализовать такое чудо?

Comment: google "C# minimal server" -> http://ajlopez.wordpress.com/2011/02/01/a-minimal-http-server-in-c/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В сторону сокетов

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы не воспользоваться стандартным  виндовым IIS.